# failed to resolve ObjCRuntime.TrampolineBlockBase

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am implementing google Admob in my Xamarin.Forms application. My android project is working perfectly but my iOS project fails to build. when I build the project it shows

> Failed to resolve "ObjCRuntime.TrampolineBlockBase" reference from "Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065"

and it also say I am missing few files.

[image]

I tried to download the mobile sdk framework for ios from https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start#cocoapods and then add to the project but I can't seem to add this framework to references.

Any kind of help is really helpful.

Comment: please do NOT post code and errors as images!!

Comment: sorry this is my first time asking help for errors, I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue from upgrading the visual studio 2019 to 16.4.5 and downgrading the Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.AdMob from 7.47.0.1 to 7.27.0.3

After doing that I restarted Visual Studio and build the project it successfully built.

Also, I referred to this [link](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/158) for help

**Edit:**
In short, Visual studio installed the new appropriate mono framework for ios which basically solved the issue here.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue on App Center. Resolved by upgrading SDK and Xcode versions in build configuration options

Comment: Same here, had to upgrade Xamarin.iOS from 13.6. to 13.18 for it to work

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else runs into this issue, I got this issue after adding the Maps sdk to iOS. I had to upgrade Xamarin.iOS from `13.6.0.12` to `13.10.0.21` to resolve the issue.